# Rust Rocket - Having trouble importing modules

Tags: rust, importerror, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I am working on a Rust project with Rocket. I am unable to get some modules imported properly into my code. For example, I am trying to import "rocket::form". Here is my cargo.toml file, and my main.rs file:

**cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "..."
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.4.10" }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = {version = "1.0"}
chrono = "0.4"
handlebars = "4.2.1"
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "*"
default-features = false
features = ["handlebars_templates", "tera_templates", "tera"]
```

**main.rs**

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

//ERROR HERE
use rocket::form::{Form, Contextual, FromForm, FromFormField, Context};
```

The above import statement gives me an error that reads "unresolved import `rocket::form`
could not find `form` in `rocket`". How can I add the "form" module to my project?

Comment: Rocket v0.4 doesn't have a `form` module, the relevant types are in the `request` module. Perhaps you've been reading the v0.5 docs or looking at v0.5 code?

Comment: I think you're right. So how would I go about getting the new version? Whenever I change the rocket version in my cargo.toml, it keeps showing an error.

Comment: Its not fully released yet, you need to explicitly depend on `0.5.0-rc.1` to get it. See all version on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/rocket/versions).

Comment: I see. If I were to continue using the same version I'm using now, how would I deal with forms in my templates?

Comment: Currently, I have a form in my template that I want to render another template, based on the user input.

Comment: You should probably create a new post with details on what you have and what you want. Because that needs more information to answer and is quite different than what this post asks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242751/discussion-between-darrel-gulseth-and-kmdreko).

Answer (score 0):

```
[dependencies]
rocket={version="0.5.0-rc.1",features=["json"]}
```

you dont need to install `serde` dependency.

```
use rocket::serde::{Serialize,Deserialize};
use rocket::form::Form;
```